# Can not find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I am developing web app with ASP.NET Core 1.1.0. My application worked with IIS Express. But when I was deployed app to IIS, I got the error "**Can not find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery'**".

I was removed **preserveCompilationContext** from project.json, but I got "**One or more compilation references are missing. Possible causes include a missing 'preserveCompilationContext' property under 'buildOptions' in the application's project.json.**" error message.

Static files (like .html) running fine.

How can I resolve this problem?

**project.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "nowarn": [],
    "copyToOutput": [ "appsettings.json", "appsettings.staging.json" ]
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "appsettings.staging.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ],
    "precompile": [ "C:\\Windows\\System32\\inetsrv\\appcmd recycle apppool /apppool.name:local.com" ]
  }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Web.Management
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLocalization(options =>
            {

            });

            // Add framework services.
            services
                .AddMvc(options =>
                {
                    options.Filters.Add(new ExceptionFilter());

                })
                .AddViewOptions(options =>
                {

                });

            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

            services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseLogger();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
                RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
                {
                    new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
                    new CookieRequestCultureProvider(),
                    new AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider()
                }
            };

            app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

            HttpContextMiddleware.Configure(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>());

            //app.UseStatusCodePages();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "AuthCookie",
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = false,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
                CookieSecure = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the error **before** removing `preserveCompilationContext` from project.json?

Comment: I am getting the error **Can not find compilation library location for package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery'** before removing preserveCompilationContext.

Comment: Did you tried `dotnet restore` from command line?

Comment: I tried now, but didn't change anything.

Comment: You got one problem, then changed something, got another problem. Which of one your asking help for? Why you mixing two problems in one question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your project.json isn't including all the dependencies of your project, which might explain why the libraries aren't found on your deployment target - how are you deploying to IIS, and can you confirm that all the required DLLs are included?

[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/) depends on:
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/) which depends on:
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/) which depends on:
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery/)

`preserveCompilationContext` is used to compile your MVC views, which may also be referencing the contents of the AntiForgery library to generate the required tokens and cookies on any forms on your site.

Comment: how did you identified this dependency - ViewFeatures depends on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery?

Comment: I used Google to find any links to the Antiforgery nuget package, whick listed the ViewFeatures package, from there it was easy to find the links into that - each package lists its direct dependencies, so you can follow them down.

Comment: I added Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery dependencies to project.json, but didn't run.

Answer (score 0):

Return `preserveCompilationContext` back, maybe?

Comment: Oops. We have two-in-one question, I was confused a little guessing which one I should answer to :)